# Tensorflow Object Detection - mAP steady, but Total Loss is dropping. Keep training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

Training an [Object Detection](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview) classifier with Tensorflow 1.12.2 and Python 3.6. Using about 20,000 images over 4 classes, and after 160K steps the mAP is pretty steady, but the Total Loss is still dropping (very slowly though). Should I keep training until the Total Loss ceases to drop or turns upward ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Total Loss turns upward, you have most likely went into the overfitting.

A good idea would be to check your current snapshot against a test data set and see if you get satisfactory results. If the results are good, I'd stop training.